# Dataset with features as SNOWMED codes and outputs as names of medications prescribed.What are some ML algorithms that suit this case?

Tags: machine-learning, data

So, i am constructing a dataset (from doctor prescription notes and diagnosis) where

X (input features) represent the various snowmed codes for illnesses/surgeries performed/chronic conditions etc.

Y is a set of pills prescribed for X.

Presently I do not have this data in a matrix format. For ex. i have the snowmed codes for an illness that reads as follows: "Diabetes, Hypertension, Cardiac arrest, Left MCA stroke". Y is the set of pills that the doctor noted down for the above.

As one can note, the above data is not in a matrix format.
There are many snowmed codes and various different pills overall. I'd like to apply ML algorithms to predict the pills for a given set of snowmed codes about the illness.

How to organize this data in a format convenient for ML? I am open to other analytics approaches as well. Any discussion in this matter will be helpful.

Comment: Is it many to one, one to many or many to many mapping? I suppose you could use multi class, multi label classification.

Comment: @Danny so, we can have a combination of diseases or illnesses in a patient and so, a combination of pills can be prescribed.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, Multi Class Classification will be the best approach. You can use Neural Network approach or K-Nearest Neighbours for this problem. Your DataFrame is going to be really sparse if you take a numeric approach.

From my point of view, the best approach is to build a vector model.

[image: Multi Class Classification]

After you arrange your data this way, it's easier to build a topic model using NLP techniques. It can also tell you which illnesses are most similar and which codes are similar.

This is what I could think of. These sort of questions are very open ended and can often lead to creative approaches. I am sure there'll be something better if you think hard enough.

Comment: Thank you. About the table,it is more like:
Patient IDs,Disease Code,Pills prescribed
1,"C300067, C23381, C352000","XYZ, PRE, GTU"
2,"C34922, C300067, C2311","GHH,KLL,GTU"

So, given a new set of codes, find pills.